# how to plot multiple plots sharing a common X-axis and Y-axis

Tags: plotting, graphics, code-request, grid-layouts

With the following `Code`, I generate various `ListLinePlot`s but I like to create the `example` figure given below:

```
ClearAll[data, time];
SeedRandom[21];
data = RandomReal[{1, 100}, {24, 12}];
time = Transpose@{{2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021}};
data1 = PrependTo[data, time // Flatten] // Transpose;
plot1 = ListLinePlot[Transpose[data1][[{2, 3}]], PlotLegends -> {2, 3}];
plot2 = ListLinePlot[Transpose[data1][[{4, 5}]], PlotLegends -> {4, 5}];
plot3 = ListLinePlot[Transpose[data1][[{6, 7}]], PlotLegends -> {6, 7}];
plot4 = ListLinePlot[Transpose[data1][[{8, 9}]], PlotLegends -> {8, 9}];
Row[{plot1, plot2, plot3, plot4}]
```

In the data matrix `data1` the first column is X-axis denoting time (2010, 2011,...,2021) and is common for all countries. For simplicity, the data in the 2nd and 3rd columns represent `country 1` for two time-series variables; and the 4th and 5th columns, `country 2`; etc. I have 12 countries consistent with the data given. There are two labels: blue and orange with names `Label 1` and `Label 2` as in the example.

This is the plot I like to produce:

[image]

Comment: See [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/)

Comment: @BobHanlon: `Grid` is not really creating the type of plot shown in the example. Thanks

Comment: Tugrul, but have you investigated the linked resource function? I am guessing it can be used for such thing as the plot type you want, by simply removing some of the vertical axes/frame edges. Investigating this method should turn fruitful for you.

Comment: @CA Trevillian: I did examine it and tried few things. My problem is to create a single X-axis for a group of countries over a fixed time period. This is where I got stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[data, time];
SeedRandom[21];
data = RandomReal[{1, 100}, {24, 12}];
time = Transpose@{{2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 
     2018, 2019, 2020, 2021}};
data1 = PrependTo[data, time // Flatten] // Transpose;

plot[n_] := Labeled[
  ListLinePlot[
   Transpose[data1][[{2 n, 2 n + 1}]],
   PlotLegends -> Placed[{2 n, 2 n + 1}, Above],
   Ticks -> {{1, 12}, Automatic},
   Axes -> If[n == 1, True, {True, False}],
   PlotRangePadding ->
    {{0, Scaled[0.05]}, Automatic}],
  StringForm["Plot ``", n], Below]

ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{plot /@ Range[4]}]
```

[image]